# Excel VBA web scrapping across mutliple pages not working

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get data from multiple pages from my company's webapp. I am able to read and get inner text from first/main page but as soon as i navigate to another page, I don't get the content of that page instead i get this as inner text printed multiple times:

> Es scheint als nutzen Sie den Internet Explorer. Um diese Anwendung zu nutzen, wechseln Sie bitte zu einem andern Browser.
> Benutzen Sie einen anderen Browser
> Es scheint als nutzen Sie den Internet Explorer. Um diese Anwendung zu nutzen, wechseln Sie bitte zu einem andern Browser.
> Benutzen Sie einen anderen Browser
> Benutzen Sie einen anderen Browser

Basically it says that i am using internet explorer, and to use this application i should change my browser.Any idea what could cause this?and how can i make it work?

My code is here:

```
Option Explicit

Const WolVidURL As String = "https://apps1.web.audi.vwg/apexaudi-sp/apex-sp/"
Public Sub parsehtml()

    Dim http As Object, html As New HTMLDocument, titleElem As Object, detailsElem As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Dim topic As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim topics As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim topicsList As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim topicID As Integer
    
    Dim sPageHTML As String
    
    Dim NextHref As String
    Dim NextURL As String
    
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", "https://apps1.web.audi.vwg/apexaudi-sp/apex-sp/ams/r/ams/home?session=109494555068111&tz=4:00", False
    http.Send
    
    html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
    
    Set topicsList = html.getElementsByTagName("ul")(2)
    Set topics = topicsList.getElementsByTagName("a")
    
    
    For topicID = 3 To topics.Length - 3
        Set topic = topics(topicID)
        
        NextHref = topic.getAttribute("href")
        NextURL = WolVidURL & Mid(NextHref, InStr(NextHref, ":") + 1)
        Debug.Print topic.innerText, NextURL
        ListTablesOnPage topic.innerText, NextURL
    Next topicID

    Set http = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ListTablesOnPage(topicName As String, topicURL As String)

    Dim http As Object, html As New HTMLDocument
    
    Dim tablevalue As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim tablevalues As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim div As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", topicURL, False
    http.Send
    
    
    'html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

    Set tablevalues = html.getElementsByTagName("div")
    Debug.Print tablevalues.Length
    
    For Each tablevalue In tablevalues
        Debug.Print tablevalue.innerText
        
    Next tablevalue
    
    
End Sub
```

I would be really grateful for your help.

Comment: Doing webscraping with `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` is very unlikely to work with websites that use JavaScript (which almost every modern web page does). Have a look at something like Selenium in combination with Google Chrome.

Comment: You can try to use an user agent in the request. Paste this line before the send line: `http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0"`

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ for your response. The problem is that i can't load this page on chrome. It has something to do with my company security reasons. Neither can i use directly InternetExplorer because it does not work and gives me error one after another.And the line you told me to paste doesn't work. It still gives me the same output.

Comment: Well then ask someone responsible in your company. This is a company issue then. Note that Internet Explorer was suspended and removed my Microsoft this year by Windows Update. Therefore IE cannot be used anymore! Get your IT staff involved.

Comment: Will do that! But since IE cannot be used and MSXML2.XMLHTTP does not work good with java using scripts,what else can you suggest that might work?The first page for this company works completely fine and i am able to print everything,it is just the problem with going from one page to another.Will something else work here?Also,will python bs4 be good for web scrapping here?